# R for loop for calculating sums based on a data frame's different columns

Tags: r, for-loop, aggregate

My current data frame looks like this:

```
# Create sample data
my_df <- data.frame(seq(1, 100), rep(c("ind_1", "", "", ""), times = 25), rep(c("", "ind_2", "", ""), times = 25), rep(c("", "", "ind_3", ""), times = 25), rep(c("", "", "", "ind_4"), times = 25))

# Rename columns
names(my_df)[names(my_df)=="seq.1..100."] <- "value"
names(my_df)[names(my_df)=="rep.c..ind_1................times...25."] <- "ind_1"
names(my_df)[names(my_df)=="rep.c......ind_2............times...25."] <- "ind_2"
names(my_df)[names(my_df)=="rep.c..........ind_3........times...25."] <- "ind_3"
names(my_df)[names(my_df)=="rep.c..............ind_4....times...25."] <- "ind_4"

# Replace empty elements with NA
my_df[my_df==''] = NA
```

What I want to script is a rather simple `for` loop that calculates the sum of the `value` column for each of the four `ind_*`columns and prints the result.

So far my very meagre attempt has been:

```
# Create a vector with all individuals
individuals <- c("ind_1", "ind_2", "ind_3", "ind_4")

# Calculate aggregates for each individual
for (i in individuals){
    ind <- 1
    sum_i <- aggregate(value~ind_1, data = my_df, sum)
    print(paste("Individual", i, "possesses an aggregated value of", sum_i$value))
    ind <- ind + 1
}
```

As you can see, I currently struggle to include the correct command to calculate the sum based on one column after another as the current output, naturally, only calculates the result of `ind_1`. What needs to be changed in the `aggregate`command to achieve the desired result (I'm a total beginner but thought of using indices for proceeding from one column to another?)?

Comment: first hint: try `colnames(my_df) <- c("value", "ind_1", "ind_2", "ind_3" ,"ind_4")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `tidyverse` as well:

```
my_df %>% 
   gather(key, Inds, -value) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(Inds)) %>% 
   group_by(key) %>% 
   summarise(Sum=sum(value))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
    key   Sum
  <chr> <int>
1 ind_1  1225
2 ind_2  1250
3 ind_3  1275
4 ind_4  1300
```

Idea is to make the data long using `gather`. Filter the `NA`s out, then group by Inds and summarize the values.

A more base R solution would be:

```
library(reshape2)
my_df_long <- melt(my_df, id.vars = "value",value.name = "ID")
aggregate(value ~ ID, my_df_long, sum, na.rm= T)
     ID value
1 ind_1  1225
2 ind_2  1250
3 ind_3  1275
4 ind_4  1300
```

Comment: The second solution taught that there was no need for a loop at all, thank you for pointing me to the respective package.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you´d want to calculate the sum if ind-column matches an expression in your individuals-vector:

```
individuals <- c("ind_1", "ind_2", "ind_3", "ind_4")

for (i in 1:(ncol(my_df)-1)){
  print(sum(my_df$value[which(my_df[,individuals[i]] == individuals[i])]))
}
```

Why do you want to use `print()` instead of storing the results in a separate vector?

Comment: I preferred printing for no particular reason. What would be needed to store them as a seperate vector inside the loop?

Comment: There are two options. You can create a vector beforehand and fill with respective data using your `i`as index or, you can `cbind()` while going through the loop. The latter option is significantly slower, however it does not matter for short vectors.